# The order of execution in Makefile - "rm -rf" does not finish on time?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, makefile, gnu-make

Makefile:

```
# Defines

BUILD_PATH ?= out
REPO_NAME ?= my_work_dir
REPO_URL ?= git@github.com:your_org/your_repo
REPO_BRANCH  := main

### Functions

define clone_repository
    echo Cloning repository...
    git -C $(1) init --quiet
    git -C $(1) remote add origin $(2)
    git -C $(1) fetch origin --progress --quiet --depth 1 $(3)
    git -C $(1) reset --quiet --hard FETCH_HEAD
endef

define get_sha1
    $(2):=$(shell git -C $(1) rev-parse HEAD)
endef

### Targets

do_the_work:
    # Prepare
    rm -rf $(BUILD_PATH)/$(REPO_NAME)
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_PATH)/$(REPO_NAME)
    # Clone
    $(call clone_repository,$(BUILD_PATH)/$(REPO_NAME),$(REPO_URL),$(REPO_BRANCH))
    # SHA1
    $(eval $(call get_sha1,$(BUILD_PATH)/$(REPO_NAME),REPO_BRANCH_SHA1))
    # Do...
    # do_something --sha1 REPO_BRANCH_SHA1
```

What I tried to do in the `do_the_work` is:

- Step 1: create an empty dir
- Step 2: clone repository
- Step 3: get sha1 from repository
- Step 4: do something with sha1 info

However, when I execute the `do_the_work`, I get error (please not that `$(BUILD_PATH)/$(REPO_NAME)` evaluates to `out/my_work_dir`):

```
fatal: cannot change to 'out/my_work_dir': No such file or directory
rm -rf out/my_work_dir
mkdir -p out/my_work_dir
echo Cloning repository...
.
.
.
etc
```

But, when I run the same command again, it executes OK! Is this because the `out/my_work_dir` is in place already? It also works if the dir is completely empty.

Seems like the Step 3 `$(eval $(call get_sha1...)` executed before the Step 1 `mkdir` finished? How do I fix this?

To me it seems that `rm -rf` gets prolonged if the dir does not exist at all.

Comment: What is the value of  `$(Q)`?

Comment: AFIK, make  waits after each child process is finished, but you could put the two commands for the _prepare_ step into a script, and at the end of the script do a `ls` of your build path. You would then see from the order of the output lines, if the execution is not completely serialized.

Comment: @Christian.K Removed the `$(Q)`, it doesn't matter.

Comment: If the error message is correctly transcribed, it reports on an error which happened _before_ these commands were executed. Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: @tripleee Added defines, this makes the min example. Just copy the code into `Makefile` and run `make`. I still get the same error, even with this min example.

Comment: Do not use `eval` or `shell` in a make recipe, this is usually wrong. make expands the recipes **before** it passes them to the shell, not during their execution by the shell.

Comment: I'm running make from the bash shell command line.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet How come it works the 2nd time I run the target?

Comment: The context of your second run is not the same. For instance, some missing directories may now exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in the `$(shell ...)` invocation in `define get_sha1` which runs when you `define` the function, not when you call it.

This seems like an overcomplication anyway; I would simply get rid of the `define` and replace the recipe with one where the result is stored in a shell variable.

```
do_the_work:
    ...
    # SHA1
    sha1=$$(git -C $(BUILD_PATH)/$(REPO_NAME) rev-parse HEAD); \
    # Do...
    # do_something --sha1 "$$sha1"
```

Comment: Works: had to change `"$$sha1"` to `"$${sha1}"`. The `"$$(sha1)"` also did not work.

Comment: The braces are unnecessary in isolation, though if you want to expand the variable next to another token, you need `$${sha1}othertext`. Confusingly, in a Makefile, `$(stuff)` is a Make function, while `$$(stuff)` is a shell command substitution (i.e. run `stuff` and replace the token with its output).

Comment: I use it in isolation, but somehow it needs {}.

Comment: It definitely doesn't need `{}`.  This is basic shell programming, which has been true for 50+ years... if you want to understand what is going on you'll have to show us an example of (a) what you used, and (b) what happened, and (c) what you expected instead.